# Does a Kafka Consumer receive a list of offsets first, before receiving the bytes/data?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm quite new to Apache Kafka and I'm currently reading *Learning Apache Kafka*, 2ed, (2015). Chapter 3, paragraph Kafka Design fundamentals says the following:

> Consumers always  consume messages    from    a   particular  partition   sequentially    and also    acknowledge the message offset. This    acknowledgement implies that    the consumer    has consumed    all prior   messages.   Consumers   issue   an  asynchronous    pull    request containing  the offset  of  the message to  be  consumed    to  the broker  and get the buffer  of  bytes.

I'm a bit thrown off by the word 'acknowledge'. Do I understand it correctly that Kafka sends the *offset* first and then the consumer uses the list of offsets to pull request the data it has not consumed yet?

Thanks in advance,

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On startup, `KafkaConsumer` issues a offset lookup request to the brokers for the specific consumer group that was configured on this consumer. If valid offsets are returned those are used. Otherwise, the consumer uses an initial offset according to `auto.offset.reset` parameter.

Afterwards, offsets are maintained mainly in-memory within the consumer. Each `poll()` sends the current offset to the broker and on broker reply consumer updates the in-memory offsets.

Additionally, in-memory offset are committed/acked to the broker from time to time. This can happen automatically within `poll()` if auto commit is enabled, or `commit()` must be called explicitly to send offsets to the broker for reliably storing them.